# Mysql: finding owner of most from list

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to find owner of as much as possible items from list.

Now it looks like:

```
SELECT Players.`name` FROM `Items` INNER JOIN `Players` ON Players.`id` = Items.`ownerId`
WHERE Players.`lvl` < Y 
GROUP BY `ownerId` HAVING SUM(lookId IN(81411,81421 (lots of it) 81551,81611)) > X
```

It returns names of players who has more than X items from list.

If it will return no rows, that means we demand too much items, so i try it again with X-1.

If it will return >15 rows, we can try to find players who has more than X+1 items from list.

Starting X is calculated from size of list.

Items has around 600k rows.

Any other way to do it? Now it takes >1 sec, so when starting X is wrong the whole process can take couple of seconds...

EDIT:

Items:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ownerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemClass` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemColor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attrId1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attrId2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attrId3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attr1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attr2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attr3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isArtifact` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `armor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `minDmg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `maxDmg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lookId` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ownerId`),
  KEY `ownerId` (`ownerId`),
  KEY `lookId` (`lookId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I don't get what u mean by sample data and required output. 
Query looks exactly like this one, just IN() list has from 1 to 3200 members.
Required output? List of Player names which has most items from that list

Comment: I'm not understanding your recursive process

Comment: @CAPSLOCK How about now?

Comment: Can you please sample data and desired output with tables structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to give a concrete answer without more detail in the question (table structure, sample data, required output, etc) but reading between the lines I would suggest adding the lookId criterion to the where clause -

```
SELECT
    `Players`.`name`,
    COUNT(`lookId`) AS `num_items`
FROM `Items`
INNER JOIN `Players` ON `Players`.`id` = `Items`.`ownerId`
WHERE `Players`.`lvl` < Y
AND `lookId` IN (81411,81421 (lots of it) 81551,81611)
GROUP BY `ownerId`
ORDER BY `num_items` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Your welcome. When posting in future please try to give as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT Players.`name` 
FROM `Items` INNER JOIN `Players` ON Players.`id` = Items.`ownerId`
WHERE Players.`lvl` < Y 
GROUP BY `ownerId` 
HAVING SUM(lookid) >= 
(select max(ownersum) - optional number goes here

from 

(select ownerid, sum(lookid) ownersum
FROM `Items` INNER JOIN `Players` ON Players.`id` = Items.`ownerId`
WHERE Players.`lvl` < Y 
group by ownerid
) 
)
```

I didn't actually try this.  One or both of the subqueries might need an alias.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I'm also a bit confused if you're looking for the player with the most Items in that list, or if you're looking to find players with more than X items in the list?

In the case of the former, the following might suffice:

```
SELECT p.name,
       COUNT(*) itemCount
FROM   players p 
       JOIN items i ON p.id=i.ownerid 
WHERE  p.lvl < _your_Y-value_
       AND lookID IN ( _your_list_ )
GROUP BY i.ownerid
ORDER BY itemCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: nevermind - nnichols just updated his/her similar answer while I was typing